# How to find the path to the certificate curl is using in Windows 10?

Tags: curl

My `curl` command seems to be passing in a cert for all my requests, and I cannot seem to find where this cert exists.

I've found [this article](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) which shows where `curl` will look for the cert, but I've checked those locations to no avail.

Is there a command in `curl` which will show what certs it is sending with the request?

Comment: Have you looked in `<user home>/.ssh`?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger nothing in there other than my ssh key I use for GitHub.